# Snakemake: using a python nested list comprehension for conditional analyses

Tags: python, list-comprehension, snakemake

I'm trying to use a (nested) list comprehension to solve run a conditional analysis using Snakemake.

Here is my rule:

```
rule partitioned_heritability_conditional:
    input:   SUMSTATS = "../results/GWAS_for_ldsc/{GWAS}_hg19_ldsc_ready.sumstats.gz",
             LDSR = expand("../results/LDSR/annotation_files/snATACseq.{CELL_TYPE_COND_A}.{EXT}.{CHR}.l2.ldscore.gz", CELL_TYPE_COND_A, = config['LDSR_CONDITIONAL'], EXT = config['PEAK_EXTENSION'], GWAS = config['LDSC_GWAS'])
    output:  "../results/LDSR/part_herit/baseline_v1.2/snATACseq_LDSR_{CELL_TYPE_COND_A}.vs.{CELL_TYPE_COND_B}_{EXT}_{GWAS}_baseline.v1.2.results"
    conda:   "../envs/ldsc.yml"
    params:  weights = "../resources/ldsc/reference_files/weights_hm3_no_hla/weights.",
             baseline = "../resources/ldsc/reference_files/baseline_v1.2_1000G_Phase3/baseline.",
             frqfile = "../resources/ldsc/reference_files/1000G_Phase3_frq/1000G.EUR.QC.",
             LD_anns = "../results/LDSR/annotation_files/snATACseq.FC.ExN.{CELL_TYPE_COND_A}.",
             out_file = "../results/LDSR/part_herit/baseline_v1.2/snATACseq_LDSR_{CELL_TYPE_COND_A}.vs.{CELL_TYPE_COND_B}_{EXT}_{GWAS}_baseline.v1.2",
             condition = "../results/LDSR/annotation_files/snATACseq.{CELL_TYPE_COND_B}.{EXT}.",
    message: "Running Prt Hrt conditional with ExN.vs.FC.InN, {wildcards.EXT} and {wildcards.GWAS} GWAS"
    log:     "../results/logs/LDSR/snATACseq.{CELL_TYPE_COND_A}.vs.{CELL_TYPE_COND_B}.{EXT}.{GWAS}_baseline.v1.2_partHerit_conditional.log"
    shell:
             "python ../resources/ldsc/ldsc.py --h2 {input.SUMSTATS} --w-ld-chr {params.weights} "
             "--ref-ld-chr {params.baseline},{params.condition},{params.LD_anns} --overlap-annot "
             "--frqfile-chr {params.frqfile} --out {params.out_file} --print-coefficients 2> {log}"
```

And here is the config file it references:

```
LDSC_GWAS:
    SCZ:
LDSR_CONDITIONAL:
    FC.ExN:
        - FC.InN
        - FC.RG
    FC.InN:
        - FC.ExN
        - FC.RG
    FC.RG:
        - FC.ExN
        - FC.InN
PEAK_EXTENSION:
    ext250bp:
```

What I'm looking to do is run this analysis for each cell type in the first level of  `LDSR_CONDITIONAL` (I'm calling `CELL_TYPE_COND_A`) conditioning separately on each of the cell types after the hyphens (`CELL_TYPE_COND_B`). In total there would be 6 analyses run. I hope it is clear from the structure of the config what I'm trying to do.

I'm struggling to properly reference the `CELL_TYPE_COND_B` in rule all such that the variables in the rule are backfilled correctly.

My rule all statement is:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("snATACseq_LDSR_{CELL_TYPE_COND_A}.vs.{CELL_TYPE_COND_B}_{EXT}_{GWAS}_baseline.v1.2.results", CELL_TYPE_COND_A = config['LDSR_CONDITIONAL'], CELL_TYPE_COND_B = [config['LDSR_CONDITIONAL'][x] for x in config['LDSR_CONDITIONAL']], EXT = config['PEAK_EXTENSION'], GWAS = config['LDSC_GWAS'])
```

You can see that I'm using a list copmprehsion to backfill `CELL_TYPE_COND_B` but I'm getting in a bit of muddle trying to get the desired output.

Presently this expand statement leads to the following:

```
["snATACseq_LDSR_FC.ExN.vs.['FC.InN', 'FC.RG']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.ExN.vs.['FC.ExN', 'FC.RG']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.ExN.vs.['FC.ExN', 'FC.InN']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.InN.vs.['FC.InN', 'FC.RG']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.InN.vs.['FC.ExN', 'FC.RG']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.InN.vs.['FC.ExN', 'FC.InN']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.RG.vs.['FC.InN', 'FC.RG']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.RG.vs.['FC.ExN', 'FC.RG']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.RG.vs.['FC.ExN', 'FC.InN']_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results"]
```

Although I feel this is almost there, this attempt is producing 9 instances of the command instead of 6 and is not referencing individual cell types for `CELL_TYPE_COND_B`. I've tried other syntax for the list comprehension but can't quite get the planets to align.

What I need is:

```
["snATACseq_LDSR_FC.ExN.vs.FC.InN_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.ExN.vs.FC.RG_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.InN.vs.FC.RG_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.InN.vs.FC.ExN_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results",  
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.RG.vs.FC.ExN_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results", 
 "snATACseq_LDSR_FC.RG.vs.FC.InN_ext250bp_SCZ_baseline.v1.2.results"]
```

I'm not wedded to using a list comprehension (or config file) if there is a more elegant solution to this problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think doing everything on one line using `expand` seems like a coding challenge! In the end, `expand` is just a convenient function to generate a list of strings. But in this case, I would prepare that list before rule all using regular python tools (for loops, string formatting, whatever...). The config file looks reasonable to me but I don't have the big picture...

Comment: Regarding the config file, I suspect the colons in `SCZ:` and `ext250bp:` should be removed? As it is, they look like key-value pairs without value assigned.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I take your (first) point. I agree the expand line is a bit unwieldy. However, the central issue really is how to populate `CELL_TYPE_COND_B` given `CELL_TYPE_COND_A`. I was thinking a config file and a list comprehension was the way to do it, but perhaps this is the wrong approach.